# Is Dean-hood largely irreversible, and if so why?

Tags: career-path, professorship, administration

In academia, I have noticed a number of cases where a professor who becomes a Dean (or other non-department administrative post like Provost) effectively permanently stops being a researcher thereafter.  Rather than serving an administrative term and then returning to research (as often happens with department heads), they end seem to stay in administration until they retire.

What I am wondering is this:

1. Is this confirmation bias in my perception, or is this a real trend?
2. If it is a real trend, is this more due to selection bias (i.e., only people who would *prefer* to administer become Deans, unlike department heads), or to having one's research so disrupted as to make it hard to continue, or to some other factor?

Comment: Maybe the title should be slightly adapted - when first reading it, I was going to suggest that may be location-dependent, as I know universities where the office of dean is cyclically forwarded among the more senior professors of each [faculty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faculty_%28division%29) once every few years. So, no dean-hood is not generally irreversible. Whether some, or many, of those professors develop a penchant (or otherwise urge) for management tasks over hands-on research, though, is a different topic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If you have a better title than "dean," please feel free to edit it in - Dean is the one I have usually known this class of positions under.

Comment: (1) Do you want to add the [tag:reference-request] tag? Right now, this question may degenerate into a collection of personal anecdotes. (2) This may depend on your country, since deans may have different responsibilities in different academic traditions. (I don't know, I'm guessing.)

Comment: @jakebeal: Something like "assuming management/administrative offices/duties" instead of "Dean-hood" maybe?

Comment: I am not sure how typical this is, but in central Europe many high-level administrative posts are occupied for many years by the same person. After you have spent 10 - 15 years as Rector or Dean and pretty much out of the loop of your research field, swooping back in may simply not be an option anymore, or at least prohibitively cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

To become a dean at a research university, you have to have some prior administrative experience. So, chances are that you were department head for 4 or 8 years before you become dean. By the time you step down as dean, you've been an administrator for more than 10 years. You may have been able to keep up some kind of research program as a department head, but that's almost unheard of for deans -- certainly not at the level where you would be able to keep a lab running, write grants to support your lab staff, etc.

In other words, when you step down as dean, you're in a situation where you likely haven't kept up with the literature in the field for a good long time, where you don't have any current grants, where you no longer have grad students and postdocs, and where you haven't been to a lot of conferences to interact with the other people in your field. If your plan is to go back into research, it's going to take a while to make that happen -- and it does, and universities usually also give deans a year of no teaching after they step down to get back into their field. Or, you can decide that your many years of administrative experience are useful skills and continue to use them in other roles.